# Separate build flavors for old vs new Android versions

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-productflavors

So, in order to support [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) on Androids < 4, I had to include the appcompat-v7 library. This library adds quite a bit of overhead in form of code and images (~600KB).

So I was thinking I might change the project a bit and generate separate packages, one for androids < 4 and one for newer androids. This should not be hard since the appropriate imports and definitions are only in a few source files (<5)

Subquestion: is it even worth the bother given that the only perceived gain is reduced package size?

Anyway, since this requires a modification in `build.gradle`, is this even possible?
How can I make this work? Naturally, when debugging, Android Studio should "know" what flavor to build when deploying to appropriate emulator (even if it's always the one with appcompat). I don't want to have to work more because of this.

Comment: Just a question, do you know how these flavors work? Anyhow, I wouldn't bother with it. In fact, I'd plea for `minSdk = 14`.

Comment: You can set up two different flavors and use minSdk targeting. Android Studio won't know which flavor to use when trying to run for a given device -- you'll have to choose the active flavor manually, though that's easily accessible from the UI. I agree with @NiekHaarman about versions, though. You shouldn't have to worry about API 4, which is **ancient**. See https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html but even Froyo is only 0.7% at this point. Anything older than that they don't worry about tracking.

Comment: Well, I still have around 5% customers on androids < 4, so I don't want to dissappoint them if I don't have to. Still, if I set up two flavors, one for minsdk 7 and the other for 14, how can I set up dependencies for these flavors? Dependencies aren't listed under the same gradle object tree, so I can't just move the apropriate definitions "where they belong".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is an older question, but I came across it while googling something similar. I found this great blog that answered a lot of my questions about flavors, and how to use them: http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/#comment-940

In your circumstance, however, I wouldn't use flavors. I would instead use a support library: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html They will allow you to use cool new features of modern Android OSes without your users actually having that version. Good luck, and I hope this was still relevant!